# twitter Api giving error using python

Tags: python, twitter

> hi i am new to python and i got this error but i have installed twitter but it's giving this error

```
import twitter
api=twitter.Api()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
api=twitter.Api()
AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

I don't know about this error as i have almost every package related to twitter

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    api = twitter.Api()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

when i give this command
python setup.py install_data
it give error like this
running install_data

```
Traceback (most recent call last) :
file "setup.py" ,line 47 , <module>
""" ,
File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\core.py" ,line 152 , in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\dist.py" ,line 975 , in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\dist.py" ,line 995 , in run_commands
command_obj.run
File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\command\install_data.py" , line 44 in run
For f in self.data_files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mixed with libraries actually the problem is that your are reading library of python_twitter and installed twitter.You need select the correct documentation.This is documentation error nothing else.You installed correct library.

Answer (score 1):

can you reinstall using,

```
sudo pip install twitter
```

or

```
sudo easy_install twitter
```

The old versions did not required OAuth but new one does.
The documentation of the latest version requires these to initiate the API

```
>>> api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',

    consumer_secret='consumer_secret', access_token_key='access_token', access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
```

Comment: i am window 7 user and i think sudo is for linux ??

Comment: I think you can still do "easy_install twitter" use this link to install setuptools for windows http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#installing-easy-install

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior as the OP on win7/64 and debian, both freshly installed (pip install -U twitter). `import twitter;twitter.Api` gives `AttributeError`.  I haven't used the module before, but from reading the start of the docs, it looks like you might have to do an OAuth authentication dance first..?

Comment: Actually I had the old version which did not required OAuth stuff. I installed the latest one. The documentation of the new version mention doing this. >>> api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',

    consumer_secret='consumer_secret', access_token_key='access_token', access_token_secret='access_token_secret')

Comment: Apart from the search... Twitter requires tokens it is documented

Comment: the OP is reading the docs of python_twitter, not twitter :-)  They both install under the name twitter, but only python_twitter has a `twitter.Api()` call that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "'module' object has no attribute 'Api'" means what it says: Python can't find anything named 'Api' inside the imported module 'twitter'.

Try `dir(twitter)` after the import statement. `dir()` will show what Python finds inside the object. If `dir(twitter)` shows an object called 'twitter', you may have to do something like `from twitter import twitter`.

Comment: ['NoAuth', 'OAuth', 'Twitter', 'TwitterError', 'TwitterHTTPError', 'TwitterResponse', 'TwitterStream', 'UserPassAuth', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'api', 'auth', 'dedent', 'oauth', 'oauth_dance', 'oauth_doc', 'read_token_file', 'stream', 'twitter_globals', 'write_token_file']

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name twitter

Comment: @munieb: Python is case sensitive. Notice that `dir(twitter)` contains 'Twitter', not 'twitter', and 'api', not 'Api'.

Comment: now i get this ['ACCESS_TOKEN_URL', 'AUTHORIZATION_URL', 'Api', 'CHARACTER_LIMIT', 'DEFAULT_CACHE', 'DirectMessage', 'Hashtag', 'List', 'REQUEST_TOKEN_URL', 'SIGNIN_URL', 'Status', 'StringIO', 'Trend', 'TwitterError', 'Url', 'User', '_FileCache', '_FileCacheError', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', 'base64', 'calendar', 'datetime', 'gzip', 'httplib', 'md5', 'oauth', 'os', 'parse_qs', 'parse_qsl', 'rfc822', 'simplejson', 'sys', 'tempfile', 'textwrap', 'time', 'urllib', 'urllib2', 'urlparse'] why i get Twittererror in it

Answer (score 0):

Where did you install the python twitter module from? I used http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/source/browse/twitter.py, and it has an Api class.

```
>>> import twitter
>>> api = twitter.Api()
```

Comment: i installed it from python official site . well i copy this code but it not run

Answer (score 0):

You've installed the wrong twitter library. I'm guessing you've done

```
pip install twitter
```

you should uninstall that library:

```
pip uninstall twitter
```

and install the correct(*) one

```
pip install python_twitter
```

(*) by correct I mean the one you're reading the documentation to :-)

Comment: I tested it on win7, so yes, it does work. If you've used easy_install to install it instead of pip, then I'm not sure if there is an easy way to uninstall (someone else might know though).

Comment: Ah.. Save this file ( https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py ) as `c:\get-pip.py` and then run `python c:\get-pip.py` to install pip.

Comment: More advice on installing pip on windows found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: i install pip when i am using this command pip install python_twitter but it give error that no such file or directory !!

Comment: He used setup.py install to install it, see his other questions.

Comment: @LennartRegebro i installed it . i have no issue on installion . but i have issue on running pip

Comment: @munieb: pip is used to install things. You have already installed your module, you don't need pip, at least not yet. The question is now: did you install the right thing? Did you install the module called "python_twitter" or the one called "twitter"? What was the filename of the package you installed?

Comment: @LennartRegebro i also got the error about Twitter .. is there difference between twitter and Twitter ?

Comment: @munieb: Then all the other comments above are correct: You installed the module called "twitter" but you are reading the documentation for a completely different module, called "python_twitter". Confusing, yes. Read the documentation on the page you linked to above instead. And yes, there is a difference. "Twitter" starts with an uppercase T and "twitter" starts with a lower-case t. Python is, as others have pointed out case sensitive. "Twitter" and "twitter" are two different names.

Comment: @LennartRegebro so i want to get trending topics from twitter which package should i use ?

Comment: @munieb: 1. I don't know. 2. That's a separate question, do one question per post. 3. The problem is not that you choose the wrong one. The problem is that you installed one, and you are reading the documentation for another. Which you now have been told multiple times. I think you need to read your asnwer more closely, it's annoying that we have to nag and repeat ourselves.